# Only get parent rows of nested tables

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have a document I am parsing with Jsoup which has a structure like:

```
  <body>
      <table cellspacing="0">
         <tr>
            <td>one</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>two</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                     <td>inner one</td>
                     <td>inner two</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>inner three</td>
                     <td>inner four</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
```

There are no `id`'s or anything to disambiguate the inner/outer tables on the page.

I want to loop through each outer rows that do not have a table inside them. Currently I have:

```
Elements rows = document.select("tr");
for (Element row : rows) {
...
}
```

But of course I am getting the row with the table as well as the rows in the inner table so I can't just check if curr row contains a table and continue in the loop.

How can I get rows 1 and two from the main table only and skip row 3 and its inner rows?

Comment: Maybe you can check the children of the row and see if any of them is a table: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#children()

Comment: But I don't want the rows of the table that were returned by `document.select("tr")` either. Currently I get row 3 of the main table (the whole thing as one row in the loop) AND the two inner rows as separate rows in the loop.

Comment: Then check the parents. All of them will have one table as parent, but some of them will have two. Those are the ones you want to exclude, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the most elegant solution, but it worked for me:

```
Elements rows = document.select("body > table > tbody > tr:not(:has(table))");
for(Element row : rows){
...
}
```

What's really odd is that I copied your HTML and still had to use the tbody selector.  if I just did `Elements rows = document.select("body > table > tr:not(:has(table))");` it wouldn't catch anything.

Printing out the results I got:

```
<tr> 
 <td>one</td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td>two</td> 
</tr>
```